# Remove an item based on its content

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, combobox

I have a combobox and would like to remove an item based on the ComboBoxItem's content.  How should I go about it? Something like this:

```
string contentToRemove = "ItemX";
combo.Items.Remove(combo.Where(x.Content.Equals(contentToRemove)));
```

Note that the code doesn't compile - I'm just representing pseudocode to try to explain what I want.

Comment: try this combo.Items.Remove(combo.First(x.Content.Equals(contentToRemove)));

Comment: @Killo - what would x be though?

Comment: Sorry I've forgot combo.Items.Remove(combo.Items.First(x=>x.Content.Equals(contentToRemove)));

Comment: It's returning this: "Error 1 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Have you added System.Linq namespace?

Comment: Yes I have. Could it be that the ItemCollection doesn't support `First`?

Comment: Sorry which platform do you use? ASP, WinForm, WPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
foreach (var item in combo.Items)
{
    if (item.Name == contentToRemove) // Check item.Name or something similar property.
        combo.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: I've considered that approach, however I was trying to accomplish it in one or 2 lines if it's at all possible. Thanks though :)

Comment: Should be combo.Items.Remove(item);

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with this approach after all :)

Comment: @KasperCottaar you can do this in one line but that is not recommended. And may become complex. You can debug this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this

```
string contentToRemove = "Mac2";

mycombo.Items.Add("Mac1");
mycombo.Items.Add("Mac2");
mycombo.Items.Remove(contentToRemove);
```

The Expression you are using will return `bool` (`true` or `false`) but not the string which is accepted by `combo.items.remove("String")`

Answer (score 0):

> Use this code

```
combo.Items.Remove({string});
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983551(v=vs.71).aspx